# Need new tag for MS-Project 2013

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't think I can create tags, but we do need one for MS-Project 2013...

Posted on the "Discussion" tag rather than "Feature Request" as my rather simple statement above got rejected under Feature Request as I was asked to narrate what I had already tried :)

Comment: At your level, you should be able to just retag with `ms-project-2013`. It shouldn't require any administrative action.

Comment: Well I never. Every day is a school day! :) I didn't realise tags were created on the fly. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tags are Auto-Vivified

Just so this question has an answer that can be accepted, I'm reposting [my comment](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/need-new-tag-for-ms-project-2013#comment1165_708) from above:

> At your level, you should be able to just re-tag with [ms-project-2013](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2013). It shouldn't require any administrative action.

To expand, tags are auto-vivified by [users with 150 reputation points](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), and the associated wikis can then be editied to explain the tag when necessary.