# Does PM.SE benefit from having Specific tags for each MS Project version?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

**Problem:** There's been a lot of edits being approved due to question retagging. Every time these edits are done, these questions go to the pm.se frontpage as latest activity, "burying" several other, actual newer or active questions. Would it be a nuisance from a community perspective?

**Background:** As of today, there's 4 different tags for MS Project:

- [ms-project-2007](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2007)
- [ms-project-2010](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2010)
- [ms-project-2013](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2013)
- [ms-project-2016](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2016)

besides the "parent" [ms-project](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project) tag.

Are there enough users using them as specific filters either to search for questions or provide answers or are they used mainly to clearly specify the software version the question is about? There's a [request for 2013 tag creation](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/need-new-tag-for-ms-project-2013) from around an year ago, so I assume they are used somehow.

I see a few approaches:

- Do nothing. It's not a problem, after all.
- Avoid usage of version-specific tags.
- Avoid massive tagging.
- Avoid massive tag approval (when tagging is done by users with low rep)

Any other better ideas?

Comment: Specificity is useful. Over-specificity is probably irrelevant. If the version matters, maybe we should clarify the use of the umbrella tag, or burninate it.

Comment: For the people like me who hadn't heard about burninate... [What does it mean to “burninate” a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/157692) :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85587/discussion-on-question-by-tiago-cardoso-does-pm-se-benefit-from-having-specific).

Comment: FYI, just used these comments for the sake of creating a room, something I'd be done regardless of comments (to summon specific involved people for discussion) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Tags Updated

There was [a discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85587/discussion-on-question-by-tiago-cardoso-does-pm-se-benefit-from-having-specific) about this in chat. After a little back-and-forth, I made some changes that will hopefully resolve this without a ton of extra work for the PMSE community.

1. I've updated the [pm-software](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software) tag to indicate that it's for stuff that doesn't already have a specific tag.
2. I've updated [ms-project](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project) to indicate when the top-level tag should be used, and when version-specific tags should be used instead.
3. The [ms-project](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project) tag also lists the available set of version-specific Project tags, so people don't need to go searching for them. Currently, these tags are:

   - [ms-project-2003](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2003)
   - [ms-project-2007](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2007)
   - [ms-project-2010](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2010)
   - [ms-project-2013](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2013)
   - [ms-project-2016](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2016)

### Ongoing Community Actions

People should feel free to retag questions they come across to fit the community's current guidelines, and to keep the tag wikis up to date. By doing your part to keep tags relevant, you're helping to improve search and prevent "topic ghettos."