# How do we stop a user from removing tags?

Tags: discussion

I've been *Rejecting* dozens of requests for a few days already to remove the MS Project version-specific tag (like ms-project-2010) on questions that are clear that they are specific to that version of MS Project.

Sometimes it's only the tag that even hints at what software and version the question related to.

As we decided [here](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/824/4384), we want to specify the version, when it's relevant.

**What can we do to stop this behavior?**

Comment: Can you link to some representative examples?

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for raising your concern - it demonstrates the community caring on keep PM.SE clean and organised. Shall we continue the previous conversation in the chat  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85587/discussion-on-question-by-tiago-cardoso-does-pm-se-benefit-from-having-specific ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 10th of November 2018, had a [discussion with moderators](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85587/discussion-on-question-by-tiago-cardoso-does-pm-se-benefit-from-having-specific) about the usage of version specific tags. From this discussion, we ended up changing the description of the parent tag, namely ms-project.

From the description of the tag, we can read:

> Use this generic tag for questions **that apply to most versions** of
>   Microsoft Project. For version-specific questions, please use an
>   alternate tag instead of the catch-all tag. Version tags currently
>   include: ms-project-2003, ms-project-2007, ms-project-2010,
>   ms-project-2013, and ms-project-2016.

In addition to that, had a [discussion with another user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88026/discussion-between-sarov-and-tiagoperes) (8th of january 2018) about these specific tags and how to use them as result of my edits. We concluded the same that was mentioned in the description tag, taking the words of [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/364217) into consideration as well as previous discussions.

This has the following implication:

- a question can't have both ms-project and ms-project-20xx. E.g.: https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15892 ; https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15886 ; https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15887 ; 
  https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15890 ; https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15898 ; https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15895 ;

*To note*: there's more pending edits, here are just some of the examples.

Comment: Tags are on *questions*, not solutions. So if someone thinks they have a problem that's specific to a single version, they should tag it that way, whether or not the *solution* might potentially work on other versions.

Comment: Still, when the solution is the same or similar in different versions, there's space for the tag to be edited?

Comment: I personally don’t want to see questions tagged with multiple version tags. There might be some occasional exceptions, but I can’t imagine one offhand. However, without you or Danny providing links to the actual questions at issue, I refuse to guess at what is right or wrong for a specific use case I haven’t seen.

Answer (score 4):

By opening a discussion, such as in a chat room, I'd suggest.

Also - are we sure that the Questions are *actually* specific to one version? And not just that the OP just happened to be having the issue in that version, so s/he put it in. But in reality, it applies to all versions.

In those cases, the tag *should* be changed.

Comment: I'd suggest to _continue_ the previous conversation at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85587/discussion-on-question-by-tiago-cardoso-does-pm-se-benefit-from-having-specific

Comment: @TiagoCardoso 'This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added.'

Comment: Thanks! Unfrozen now! :)